# Allow VNC session and main session to use different mozc state

Tags: 16.04, vnc, mozc

I've set up `vnc4server` on my machine (it's not working fully, but that's another issue) and a colleague is logged in and using it OK.

However, when I tried to switch to Japanese the conversion window popped up with his terminal commands appearing, and then he switched back to English, but I would not expect the IME settings to be shared like this. Is there some way to tell `mozc` to only work with the current terminal session or disable it in the VNC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible solution

Try [to configure](https://moritzmolch.com/2287) your `ibus-mozc`:

1. Open `System Settings`;
2. Click on `Text Entry`;
3. Select `Japanese (Mozc) (IBus)`;
4. Switch the central options:

   - from:

     - `Use the same source for all windows`.
   - to:

     - `Allow different sources for each window` and active too,

       - `New windows use the default source`.

[image: ibus text entry window]